# How can I put the title and author closer together in PyLaTeX?

Tags: python, flask, latex, pylatex

I'm using PyLaTeX as a means to generate pdfs (as part of a flask web app), and I can't get the title and author to be at a distance other than the the default one.

My code as of now looks like this (this works as a means of collapsing the date section)

```
doc.preamble.append(Command('title', f"This is my personalized title with a {variable}"))
doc.preamble.append(Command('author', "This is the author"))
doc.preamble.append(Command('date', NoEscape(r'\vspace{-3ex}'))) #didn't want a date
doc.append(NoEscape(r'\maketitle'))
```

**Trying it with vspace**

The issue is that the same `\vspace{-3ex}` seems to do nothing at all if I place it inside the author command (the space between title and author stays the same). Also placing it inside the title changes the space **above** the title, not below.

```
doc.preamble.append(Command('title', NoEscape(r'\vspace{4.0cm}' + f"Title with {variable}"))) #adds space on top
doc.preamble.append(Command('author', NoEscape(r'\vspace{-3.0cm}' + "Author"))) #this changes nothing
```

**Trying it with titling**

I've also tried to use the `titling` LaTeX package, but I can't get it to work from PyLaTeX. I think it imports it correctly, but then I can't for example change the posttittle like the other stuff:

```
doc.packages.append(Package(titling)) #this seems fine
doc.preamble.append(Command('posttitle','\vspace{-3.0cm}')) #things like this crash the compiler
...
doc.preamble.append(NoEscape(r'\posttittle{\vspace{-3.0cm}}')) #things like this don't work either
```

Though I may not be using the titling properly inside of PyLaTeX (I learned most of all this yesterday, so hm...).

Comment: If you want to put title and author together ... wouldnt `doc.preamble.append(Command('title', f"This is my personalized title with a {variable}" + NoEscape(r'\vspace{-3ex}'))
doc.preamble.append(Command('author', "This is the author"))` make more sense? I have NO clue about pylatex - just simple latex - not sure if that is how pylatex works

Comment: Does it matter? As far as I understood, ```\vspace``` acts after the current line is written, so shouldn't it have the same effect independently of where it appears? I'll try it though.

Comment: Well... you win. hahahahahah

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, as @Patrick Artner pointed out, the order matters.

```
doc.preamble.append(Command('title', NoEscape(f"Title with {variable}" + r'\vspace{-1cm}')))
```

From the docs I understood that `\vspace` affected the line it appeared in (independently of where on the line it was placed). It seems not (having `\vspace` at the beginning changes the height of the title, but having it at the end changes the space between the title and the author).